# Bootstrap scrollspy and tabs dont work together

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I am having some problems to make work together scrollspy and tabs components.

As you can see in the follow example, every time that I scroll the content, it works funny, i tested in different ways, and it seems the problem is because the tabs are hidden... but I sincerely dont know how to fix this.

I created an example here:
http://bootply.com/66613

Is there a way not to scroll certain elements inside of a scrollable element, I was thinking an attribute not scroll or something like that, I couldnt find any documentation about this.

Thanks!